# Is it possible to distinguish the binary content of a gpg-encrypted file from a random blob of data?

Tags: gnupg

I have encrypted the file `some_file` to be decipherable by `some_recipient` with:

```
gpg --encrypt --recipient some_recipient some_file
```

Which results in a file `some_file.gpg`.

My question is: is the content of `some_file.gpg` distringuishable from random data in any way?

Taking a quick look with `xxd` at the actual binary content of the `.gpg` file, I cannot see any obvious header or similar that would shout out "here is some gpg-encrypted binary data", but I may be missing / ignoring something. So, I am wondering: given only the binary content of the `.gpg` file without knowing this content comes from an actual `.gpg` encrypted file (let us say the binary content of the file gets dumped to my disk at some point by my OS through a caching mechanism), can anybody establish that these binary data are actually gpg encrypted data instead of just purely random data (I always "wipe" disks by filling with random data at OS installation, so any "not overwritten" part of my disk will already look like random data)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `gpg --encrypt` has a specific format and contains metadata (e.g. the version and algorithm identifiers) which is necessary to decrypt the file later. It cannot just be the ciphertext, because then the receiver wouldn't know how exactly the content was encrypted.

You can inspect the format with
`gpg --list-packets encrypted_file.gpg`

So, yes, the file can clearly be recognized as a gpg-encrypted file.

Comment: Any way to avoid any form of header / recognizable data and keep just the encrypted, pseudo random looking data? (Of course I understand this means some additional data should be provided with the decrypt command, such as algorithm, key to use, and similar metadata).

Comment: You could write a gpg patch or wrapper program to strip the meta data after encryption, store it separately from the ciphertext and then add it back before decryption. If that's worth it, and if there are better tools depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: A proper encryption won't make decryption any easier just because you know what it is. This is classic security via obscurity (hiding type of encryption). It's not secure. Don't solve your problem this way.

Comment: @Zorglub29 What you are looking for is one way of doing "plausibly deniable encryption". If you search this term, you will find tools and software that do what you want.